# Kubuntu 20.04 LTS, PC power just shuts off randomly

Tags: kubuntu, power-management, shutdown

PC powers off randomly. Other devices on the same power strip continue to run so I know it's the PC.

I tried looking at the Ksyslog app but could not find any indication of the problem, albeit with my noob eyes.

Where do I begin troubleshooting this problem and what am I looking for in the Ksyslog?

Comment: Start by looking at your temperatures. If your temps are nice and cool, try a different power supply. Ubuntu does not have an "unexpected shutdown" feature --who would want that?-- but your hardware does

Comment: Laptop or Desktop?

Comment: @user535733 CPU temps running 38C to 50C so I think I'm good. Will keep an eye out thank you.

Comment: @heynnema This is an HP z640 workstation

Comment: How many SATA devices? What are they?

Comment: FYI: You can't disqualify that the problem isn't with your power source just because nothing else appears to have turned off on the same power strip.

Comment: @heynnema 3 SSD's ranging from 240gb to 1TB. 1 8TB 7200rpm HD. Might I add this computer has been running without any power issues for over 2 years.

Comment: @Nmath I see your point

Comment: Can you temporarily disconnect power from the 8TB and see if the problem reoccurs?

Comment: @heynnema I could, however never had a problem with the power draw and the 8TB is very low power. If power draw is what you are getting at, I could remove a CPU (dual xeon).

Comment: @user535733 I've increased my idle fan through the BIOS and CPU's running 3-5C lower. no shutdowns so far.

Comment: Anyone know if there are any logs that might give me a hint as to what shut it down in the first place?

Comment: You said *"CPU temps running 38C to 50C*", so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: /var/log/syslog

Comment: @heynnema any key words I should look for or just look at the time stamp at the time of shutdown?

Comment: Just look at some time slightly before a shutdown, if you know it.

Comment: Is your CPU or RAM overclocked?

Comment: no overclock, got a bunch of these errors before the shutdown




2/2/22 5:03 PM kernel mce_notify_irq: 59 callbacks suppressed
2/2/22 5:03 PM kernel mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
2/2/22 5:03 PM kernel mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
2/2/22 5:04 PM kernel mce_notify_irq: 59 callbacks suppressed
2/2/22 5:04 PM kernel mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
2/2/22 5:04 PM kernel mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged